# Read all file chars using fgets from START to STOP string

Tags: c, string, file, fgets, stdio

i need to read whole file between START and STOP strings and write that string into new file.

For example file1.txt = "Hello START world! STOP" 
and write to new file2.txt = "world!" (without spaces after START and before STOP)

I have that code already
I can use only 4 functions: fopen(), fclose(), fgetc(), fputc()

My code wont work properly. It starts from START but at the end it writes space STO characters.

Could you help me with that algorithm? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
    FILE *input;
    FILE *output;
    char c;

    char start[] = "START";
    char stop[] = "STOP";

    int started = 0;
    int stopped = 0;

    input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    output = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    c = fgetc(input);
    int i = 0;
    while(c != EOF) {
        if(started == 0) {
            //find start
            if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == ',' || c == '.')
                i = 0;
            else 
            {
                if(c == start[i])
                    i++;
                else
                    i = 0;
            }       
            if(i == 5) {
                started = 1;
                i = 0;
                c = fgetc(input); //move space
            }
        } else {
            //write letters until stop
            if(stopped == 0) {          
                //find stop
                if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == ',' || c == '.')
                    i = 0;
                else 
                {
                    if(c == stop[i])
                        i++;
                    else
                        i = 0;
                }       
                if(i == 4) {
                    stopped = 1;
                    i = 0;
                    break;
                }               
            }
            if(c != 'S' && c != 'T' && c != 'O' && c != 'P')
                fputc(c, output);
        }
        c = fgetc(input);
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `c` variable needs to be an int, not a char, btw: http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: This code is completely broken regardless. The last `if` condition to determine whether to write a character or not will only stand a chance of "working" (term used loosely) if you also have no intent on writing any `S`, `T`, `O` ,or `P` characters, including when they are NOT  contiguous to form the word `STOP`.

Comment: You'll need to read any sequence of white space and store the characters, and any following S, T and O (in sequence) until you get to a P or not-P.  If you get a not-P (or if you get something other than an S after the blanks, or something other than a T after the S, or something other than an O after the T), you output the saved characters and the character that doesn't match.  If you get a P (after blanks, and S, T, O), you discard all the saved characters and stop your processing (or stop until the next occurrence of `START`).

Comment: I would break problems into two loops for simplicity. The first loop simply reads until it finds a complete 'START'. If it never finds it, it can just cleanly exit. If it does find it, then start a new loop reading a char at a time, keep a matchIndex variable against the word "STOP", starting at 0, incrementing if you get a match. Once this index == 4 (length of "STOP"), you can stop. If matchIndex is > 0 and the char doesn't match "STOP"[matchIndex], then you must print out the the first matchIndex characters of "STOP" before setting matchIndex back to 0;

Comment: I would break the problem into three different loops, (1) locate `"START"`; (2) read/discard whitespace following `"START"`; and (3) read until `"STOP"` located, buffering all `'S'`, `'T'` and `'O'` until `'P'` is found and if not `'P'` (e.g. `"STOW"`) write the buffered characters out and continue. You will want to validate `c != EOF` following each loop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want you could read the whole file and then use srtok function for separating the text into tokens(using the space character as separator).

Then you could compare each token and look for your start and stop conditions.

According your example this should help.

Ref: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Comment: You missed the part about **"I can use only 4 functions: fopen(), fclose(), fgetc(), fputc()"**?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Yeap, I miss that part.